# Python - Kivy - Python has stopped working during installation of kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to install kivy to try out the GUI application using python, however after installing Visual Studio C++ 141 build and trying to install kivy using `python -m pip install kivy` I get the python has stopped working pop-up.
Anyone knows what might be a problem?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I just found the following and installed python 3.7.3 and was able to pip install kivy:

pip pulls from PyPI and, at the time of this writing, Kivy 1.11.1 on PyPI only has wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.5 - 3.7.

Based on your Pastebin output, you appear to be using Python 3.8. This means that Python cannot use any of the pre-built wheels from PyPI right now. And pip appears to be running into issues compiling Kivy from scratch for Python 3.8 (which is not unusual for more complex projects/modules on Windows).

As a general recommendation, you should consider using a current version of e.g. Python 3.7 (ex. Python 3.7.6) with Kivy, as this should solve the problems you are encountering with little additional effort.

Multiple Python Installations

On Windows, you can have multiple versions of Python installed without one installation affecting the other(s). Simply install the additional version of Python you wish to use via the normal installation process (e.g. with the vanilla installer from python.org linked above).

Hope this helps you as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution will be using kivy master branch directly rather than waiting for the wheel update.

**Run the below command:**

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```